# What is the difference between the NGEN and NGEN Critical scheduled tasks?

Tags: .net, ngen

I have a situation where a client is needing to manually run the *.NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 Critical* scheduled task to prevent a `System.StackOverflowException` from occurring in **PresentationFramework.dll**.

The application in question is a 32-bit native image built in Borland Delphi 6 which acts as a host for the .NET assembly via some sort of magic trickery.  (i.e. I don't remember exactly how it does it...maybe via COM???)  Up until a few months ago this application was working fine.

After the scheduled tasks runs, the application works fine as it did before UNTIL the next Windows Update whereupon our client will need to manually run the scheduled task again.  (the Windows Updates are pushed out by their IT department)

The .NET assembly is also part of another .NET application which runs fine without the error, indicating it is something do with the way the .NET dll is hosted in the native application.

This is occurring on all the machines in one particular office, which are all running Windows 10.  We have other clients running the same software who have not reported the issue, so it's a bit bewildering.